# Unable to retrieve JSON data using Ionic AngularJS framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm doing Lynda's tutorial on Ionic framework and once I finally got onto some backend coding, I've run into this issue. Basically just generated the app and opened up the www/js/app.js file to add a controller to it with this code:

```
.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.artists = data;
    });
}]);
```

www/js/data.json is the .json file with the data that I'm supposed to refer to in the index.html file using this code:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat='item in artists' class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap">
    <img src="img/{{item.shortname}}_tn.jpg" alt="{{item.name}} Photo">
    <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
    <h3>{{item.reknown}}</h3>
    <p>{{item.bio}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

But the retrieved data is null, as the img tag shows no value upon inspection, same as any other tag containing the 'item' data reference. What can I try?

Comment: Do you have error in console ?

Comment: I'm using notepad++ as my editor... sorry.

Comment: console from web browser i mean.

Comment: He's asking if you get any error in the F12 developer tool console of the browser that you are testing in.

Comment: using browser dev tools check for any console errors

Comment: Yes, the following `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   %7B%7Bitem.shortname%7D%7D_tn.jpg`

Comment: I think you are pointing to wrong source url. Can you check the source url is correct?

Comment: All the image resource files are located within the www/img folder and all have names that follow the structure of JSON shortname field + _tn.jpg. As far as I can tell, everything is on point.

Is it possible that browser is actually interpreting the curly braces wrongly? The &7D instead of them could be what's causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
you can try replacing data with below code: 

$scope.artists = data.artists;

OR

$scope.artists = data.speakers;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, changing it to `$scope.artists = data.artists` made it work,